# MySQL query to exclude highest and lowest count

Tags: mysql

I have following table in MySql

```
Number
1
2
3
2
3
4
4
4
```

I would like to get numbers by count but with excluded highest and lowest count. This should be the result

```
Number  Count
2       2
3       2
```

Please help me with this query.

Comment: What if there are ties for the highest and lowest counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT number, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY number
HAVING cnt <> (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM mytable
               GROUP BY number
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1)
       AND               

       cnt <> (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM mytable
               GROUP BY number
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

The two subqueries used in the `HAVING` clause return the minimum and maximum count. Hence the two predicates of the `HAVING` clause filter out the groups with the highest and lowest count.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is using `user variable` and `sub-query`.

### Query needed:

```
select Number, Count
from (
    select Number, count(*) as Count, @rank := @rank+1 as rank
    from t1 cross join (select @rank := 0) param
    group by Number
    order by Count ) t2 
where rank not in (1, @rank);
```

### Demo:

```
create table t1(Number int);
insert into t1 values(1),(2),(3),(2),(3),(4),(4),(4);

select Number, Count
from (
    select Number, count(*) as Count, @rank := @rank+1 as rank
    from t1 cross join (select @rank := 0) param
    group by Number
    order by Count ) t2 
where rank not in (1, @rank);
```

### Output:

```
mysql> select Number, Count
    -> from (
    -> select Number, count(*) as Count, @rank := @rank+1 as rank
    -> from t1 cross join (select @rank := 0) param
    -> group by Number
    -> order by Count ) t2
    -> where rank not in (1, @rank);
+--------+-------+
| Number | Count |
+--------+-------+
|      2 |     2 |
|      3 |     2 |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select number,count(number)
from numbers 
where number not in ((select max(number) from numbers),(select min(number) from numbers)  )
group by number
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27795/13)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight look at sqlfiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

First select all rows except the maximum and minimum numbers.
Then find the count(number) from the result set.

**Query**

```
select t.number, count(t.number) as `Count` from(
    select * from your_table_name
    where number not in (
        select max(number) from your_table_name
    )
    and number not in (
        select min(number) from your_table_name
    )
)t
group by t.num;
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT column FROM tbl
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20

SELECT MIN(taka) AS mintaka, MAX(taka) AS maxtaka 
FROM (SELECT taka FROM tbl LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20);